# Batch normalization before or after channel-wise concatenation?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, normalization

I have a block in a CNN that splits the input channel-wise in half, and one half goes through a regular 3x3 2d convolutional layer, and the other goes through a dilated 3x3 2d convolutional layer. After each is a batch normalization, then an activation function. They are both then concatenated again channel-wise before going through another 2d convolutional layer. Surely, however, when concatenating them there are two different distributions in the data, since the batch normalization was performed on each half separately?
Should batch normalization be performed after they're concatenated instead?

Comment: So I've tested, and I seem to get the best results by doing both. So if I have a batch normalization after each conv, and then again after concatenation.